# Web Scraping Blocked by Robots Meta Directives

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on a web scraper to access scheduling data from a website. Our company has full access to this website and data via login credentials. With dynamic site navigation required, I am using Selenium for automated data scraping, Python, and BeautifulSoup to work with the HTML structure. With all variables defined, I have the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import lxml.html as lh

opt = Options()
opt.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=opt, executable_path=<path to chromedriver.exe>)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(<path to chromedriver.exe>)

driver.get(<website login page URL>?username=' + username + '&password=' + password)
driver.get(<url of website page with data>?start_date=' + start_date + '&end_date=' + end_date +'&type=Excel')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
print(soup)
```

The result of the print(soup) is as follows:

```
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
<meta content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" name="ROBOTS"/>
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"/>
<meta content="initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
<meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
</head>
<body> ... irrelevant ... </body></html>
```

Before any questions, I do not have much knowledge regarding robot or HTTP requests. My questions are:

1. When I run a headless driver as above, the scrape is blocked by robots. When I run a regular, non-headless driver where an automated browser opens, the scrape is successful. Why is this the case?
2. What is the best method to get around this? The scrape is legal and non-exploitive as we practically have full access to the data we are scraping (we are a registered client). Will using the requests library solve this problem? Are there other methods of running headless web drivers that won't get blocked? Is there some parameter I can change that prevents the block?
3. How do I see the robots.txt file of a website?

Comment: i think it'll be difficult to provide an exact answer to your Q because the website you want to scrape is not mentioned? others need to replicate the issue you've highlighted.

Comment: https://www.scantronassessment.com/sitescheduler/asp/login.asp

Comment: @Kevin what is the output of `navigator.webdriver` within Chrome ? open `Chrome` console via shortcut Option + ⌘ + J (on macOS), or Shift + CTRL + J (on Windows/Linux)

Comment: robots.txt is commonly located at the root of a website like example.com/robot.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following code to hide the webdriver

```
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
```

also, add this to your chromedriver options

```
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, the robots.txt file on many websites incorporates blocking technologies meant to detect and block scrapers. This usually happens when the site is able to capture your browser fingerprint (such as the header case and order, the versions of the TLS and HTTP protocols) and then there is a mismatch between that and the browser fingerprint information retrieved from the scraper's reqeust.

If avoiding getting blocked or detected as a crawler is your primary concern, I would suggest maybe having a look at a more advanced off-the-shelf scraper like Bright Data. Their scraper provides device/browser fingerprint emulation (including header information) and rotating residential proxies which can be super helpful for this as opposed to data center proxies that VPNs generally offer ([here's](https://get.brightdata.com/gm-differences-between-datacenter-and-residential-proxies%5D%20of%20the%20differences) a good breakdown).

Not sure if this is exactly the solution you're looking for, but in any case, this [blog post](https://get.brightdata.com/bd-web-unlocker-enables-better-fingerprinting-auto-unlocking-and-captcha-solving) talking about their unlocker infrastructure may be of help.